# Word or phrase for the moment/reason/motive you reveal to someone why you had acted a certain way prior to parting ways

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A massive cliché in action movies (especially James Bond), but is there actually a word for that moment when the evil villain reveals their deadly plot to the action hero before (usually attempting and failing at) killing them?

If there is no word for this, is there a phrase for the "reason that this was done" i.e. if you asked the villain why they did it (apart from probably for personal satisfaction).

In a similar (but un-deadly scenario), is there a word/phrase/motive for the **reason** someone might feel like they wanted to tell someone (they wouldn't see again) why they had acted in a certain way prior to the final parting (i.e. telling them about past events during their final encounter)? e.g. "I acted like that because I really liked you and what you did made me feel bad at the time, and I felt like I needed to tell you because..." (is this even a good idea haha)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BondVillainStupidity, http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JustBetweenYouAndMe http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilGloating

Answer (score 6):

> [[the] **reveal**](http://johnaugust.com/glossary)
>    *the moment in which previously withheld information about characters or plot is unveiled.*

Comment: Definitely.  AKA The *big* reveal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reveal_(narrative).

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple suggestions for the reason:

**Vindicate:**

- to show that (someone or something that has been criticized or doubted) is correct, true, or reasonable
- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vindicate

**Justify:**

- to provide or be a good reason for (something)
- to prove or show (something) to be just, right, or reasonable
- to provide a good reason for the actions of (someone)
- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/justify

I think the villainous info dump is usually referred to as **monologuing** and the link that @MετάEd shared from tvtropes is pretty much spot on.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with ***[parting shot](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/parting-shot.html)***:

> A final remark, usually cutting or derogatory, made just before
>   departing.

The parting shot can (and usually does, at least in movies) include a *revelation*.

Answer (score 0):

TVTropes (a website that catalogues pop culture cliches) has it listed as **Motive Rant**. See: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MotiveRant. For a more general answer I'd go with **Impetus** which basically means the driving force behind some action.

Answer (score 0):

The **reason** for revealing the plan is the **[hubris](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hubris)** of the villain.

> 1. Excessive pride or self-confidence.
>
> 1.1. (In Greek tragedy) excessive pride towards or defiance of the gods, leading to nemesis.

*His failure was brought on by his hubris.* - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hubris)

Obviously the villain would not put hubris forth as reason, but an outside observer very well might.

Answer (score 0):

In your last paragraph you emphasise the urge to let the truth be known now that we will likely never see each other again. *Not leaving anything unsaid* and *Clearing the air* and *Not wishing there to be [remain] any bad blood between us* and *Having it all out in the open* are idioms that are often used in such situations.

But this is between two people who have worked together, or lived together, and things have gotten sticky between them; hardly the villain reveals their master plan situation.